Inequality of $L^p$ norms on Random Variables
Suppose that $X,Y$ are random variables, and suppose that conditional on $X$, $Y$ has mean zero and is symmetric around 0. I know that when $p$ is an even integer, it is true that $\| X+Y \|_p \ge \| X \|_p$ (proof of this below). My question is: is true for general $p > 0$?
Proof of the above:
\begin{align*}
\| X+Y  \|_{L^p} &=  \left( \mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^p]  \right)^{1/p} \\
&=  \left( \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{m=0}^{p} \binom{p}{m} X^m Y^{p-m} \right] \right)^{1/p} \\
&\ge  \left( \mathbb{E} \left[ X^p \right] \right)^{1/p} \\
&= \| X\|_{L^p},
\end{align*}
where inequality is true because all of the powers of $X$ and $Y$ are even, and the odd ones disappear because $Y$ is symmetric conditional on $X$.

I figured this out! Consider
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} [|X+Y|^p] &=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|^p | X  ]] \\
&\ge \mathbb{E} [  |\mathbb{E}[X+Y|X]|^p ] \\
&= \mathbb{E} [  |X|^p ],
\end{align*}
where the inequality is Jensen's. Then, taking the $1/p$th power concludes the proof.
